# How to create a class connection?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Can anyone help me with a question, I believe it's simple, but unfortunately I still have a hard time getting things to communicate with each other in Godot.

I created a scene which I made as main class (bullet.tscn) and through it I create the various projectiles that can be used in the game. My question is regarding the code I created for the attack action... how do I make all these types of projectiles accessible to my character? "export(Array, PackedScene) var bullets" maybe... never used. Well let's assume it can use two types of projectiles, however, when I need to update the amount of projectiles, it's going to be a mess. I managed to think of a way to do it, however, I don't know how to program and that's where my doubt lives.

When I perform the attack action, in addition to knowing, through the code created for this state, which projectile I am using, communicate with the main class bullet.tscn the need to use the function to increase and decrease the ammunition (it is the same for all projectiles... so that's why leave it in the main one, so with few lines I solve). The maximum number of projectiles for each ammunition must be linked to the script of each projectile in particular, just modifying the variable (export). I don't know if my question is too complex...

Then I'll have to create something to increase the maximum projectile limit, through in-game upgrades (I have no idea how to do it either). LOL

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'd like to help but would be good to see some code and see exactly what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Undoubtedly it would be more interesting, the thing is that I don't know how to build the code to show. LOL
I have something, I can share...

Comment: So basically you have a variable on each ammo type that says what's the max amount of that ammo the player has at once, and you want to access that variable from your player script?

Comment: Another question is why you need to have all the projectiles accessible to the character? Would there be a problem using the reverse (let the player accessible to the projectile)  ?

Comment: I strongly believe you need a Weapon class. Probably a custom resource type? - My mind is elsewhere, but that is probably where I would start.